# number_field_tag in Rails is creating a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, partial

Thank you for allowing me here. I have searched and searched for the answer to this riddle.
I am trying my first Rails app, and everything is straightforward: the index page summons a `_calc.html.erb` partial. And summons it, and summons it...
ETA FIXED! CODE BELOW -> the offending line is highlighted for those who encounter the error in the future:

```
<%= form_for :plan do %>
    <em>OK, how much do you make?</em>
    <%= number_field_tag :salary %>
    <% puts "The salary field is producing the loop" %>
<h3><span id="more">Continue</span></h3>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#more").click(function(){
    $("div.subcalculator").animate({opacity: 1},800);
});
$("#moremore").click(function(){
    **<% if check_expenses(:salary, :weeklyExpenses) %>**
    $("div.sub_subcalculator").animate({opacity: 1},800);
    **<% end %>**
});
</script>
<div id="subcalculator" class="subcalculator">
```

ETA ERROR: The screen that now comes up on localhost:3000 is

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

And in the Rails Server it says:

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1
>   at 2013-11-03 11:30:37 -0500
>  Processing by IntroController#index
>   as HTML
>  The salary field is producing the loop
>  The salary
>   field is producing the loop
>  The salary field is producing the
>   loop
>  The salary field is producing the loop
>  The salary field
>   is producing the loopRendered plan/_calc.html.erb (1.3ms)
>   Rendered plan/_calc.html.erb (2.2ms)
>    Rendered
>   plan/_calc.html.erb (3.1ms)
>    Rendered plan/_calc.html.erb
>   (4.0ms)
>    Rendered plan/_calc.html.erb (4.8ms)
>    Rendered
>   plan/_calc.html.erb (5.6ms)
>    Rendered plan/_calc.html.erb
>   (6.5ms)
>    Rendered plan/_calc.html.erb (7.4ms)
>    Rendered
>   plan/_calc.html.erb (8.2ms)
>    Rendered plan/_calc.html.erb
>   (9.1ms)

I did ascertain the loop occurs in the top of the partial; the first helper is for a `number_field_tag` and that seems to render over and over but the subsequent `number_field_tag(s)` do not. 
I tend to compulsively rake the routes and migration if I've made even tiny changes, so if that helps at all:

```
root        GET    /                         intro#index
intro_index GET    /intro/index(.:format)    welcome#index
 plan_index GET    /plan(.:format)           plan#index
            POST   /plan(.:format)           plan#create
   new_plan GET    /plan/plan/calc(.:format) plan#new
  edit_plan GET    /plan/:id/edit(.:format)  plan#edit
       plan GET    /plan/:id(.:format)       plan#show
            PATCH  /plan/:id(.:format)       plan#update
            PUT    /plan/:id(.:format)       plan#update
            DELETE /plan/:id(.:format)       plan#destroy
```

Comment: I've edited your question so it is easier to read. We'll need more details about the error. Take a closer look at the server output, perhaps above the "rendered" info. Is this in development? Because it should not be reporting "something went wrong" in development mode, but should output a descriptive error message.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Roche, and I apologize for not being better with posting. I am adding more details above as the comments box does not like code.